# Echo different images depending on array value

Tags: php, arrays

I want to echo a different image depending on if a key exists or not.

Here is an example of the array I'm using

```
["Person"] => array(11) {
    ["id"] => int(38482818123)
    ["weight"] => int(140)
    ["height"] => int(65)
}
["Name"] => array(2) {
    ["firstname"] => string(4) "John"
    ["lastname"] => string(5) "Smith"
}
```

So the name field isn't always there. I need to show`image a` if the name is there and `image b` if there is no name.

What I've tried:

```
foreach($personArray as $person)
{
    if ($person['Name'] != '')
    {
        echo "<img src='image-a.png'>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<img src='image-b.png'>";
    }
}
```

Now the problem I have is that even though the person has a name, I'm seeing both images on the page instead of just `image a`

I have also tried using `array_key_exists("Name", $personArray);` but for some reason I am getting `bool(false)` as a result.

[image: Array]

Comment: You're iterating an array. So if some people have names and some don't, you'll probably see multiple copies of each image.

Comment: [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) might be the function you're looking for. `!empty($person['Name'])`

Comment: From what I can see, the Person array does not contain a name value to begin with. Name is a separate array altogether?

Comment: That's a typo on my part I believe, I updated the question with an image of the array as I see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `empty()` like below:-

```
 if(!empty($personArray['person']['Name'])){ 
    //image a code
 }else{
    //image b code
 }
```

Comment: It's still showing both, I don't understand why it is doing that for an array with 1 person.

Comment: Can I use this outside of the loop?

Comment: my array is json_decoded inside a variable named `$result`. I just tried your solution outside of my loop and it gives image 2 if the name field is filled in.

Comment: Let me take a picture of my exact array and post it in my question, I'm still getting the second image when the field is filled in. I might be portraying it wrong in my question.

Answer (score 3):

First, it seems that you have a different array for the Name, I wonder why you don't have something like:

```html
 ["Person"] => array(11) {
    ["id"] => int(38482818123)
    ["weight"] => int(140)
    ["height"] => int(65)
    ["firstname"] => string(4) "John"
    ["lastname"] => string(5) "Smith"
    }
```

As per that case, the array index with the key "firstname" , "lastname" might not be set for some person. So you can check if that index is set using

> isset(); 
>   function

Try:

```html
foreach($personArray as $person)
{
    if (isset($person['firstname']) && isset($person['lastname']) ) // You may use or as well ||
    {
        echo "<img src='image-a.png'>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<img src='image-b.png'>";
    }


   //  Or as a short hand if statement:

  echo (isset($person['firstname'])&& isset($person['lastname'])) ? "<img src='image-a.png'>" : "<img src='image-b.png'>";
}
```

**Edit: 1**
You still seem to be using two different arrays: Person and Name. Doing this, you cannot say which particular person has the name values or not:
For eg: if you have 10 persons and have the Name array with firstname, lastname for just 7 person then you will have person[0], person[1].....person[9] and Name[0]...Name[6].
As per your construct, there is no any reference / link between the Person and Name array. Suppose 1st person has Name, then Person[0] and Name[0] would represent the same person. But if the first 3 Person do not have Name, then Person[3] will have Name[0]...and so on, hence, it is not possible to identify to which Person does a particular Name array belong to. And Note: you cannot use Name["firstname"] inside the foreach() of Person. Because, your name array would be of the form Name[0]["firstname"], Name[0]["lastname"] and so on.

Bottom Line:

If possible, try to use / include the firstname, lastname in the Person array itself. That way, when iterating / looping through the Person array using foreach() you can check if each of these person have firstname , lastname or not: Hope this is clear.

Comment: I tried your answer but I still got both images. I might have portrayed the array poorly in my question but I took a picture of it if you would like to take another look.

Comment: Your code also works with my array outside of the loop, thank you!

Comment: Well great then :)